# mysqli_connect() not working in function stored in external file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've seen this issue in a few threads, but the suggestions I've had a chance to try have worked yet.

I want to store all of my functions (and a few variables) in a file, then include that file in my pages. Here's my includes.php:

```
<?php
$title = "Whatever Tattoos";

function databaseConnect()
{
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', "test", "test", "tats");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
}

?>
```

In my test, I call the databaseConnect() function but my query does not return anything. If I pull out the code and place it directly into my test file, it works. I figured it was an issue with variable scope, but I've tried to return the $con variable - no go; extract() the $con variable - no go; and set $con to global - no go.

To complicate matters, if I create a variable like so:

```
$test = "this is a test";
```

inside of the function, I can call it in my main code with no problem. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the query code:

```
databaseConnect();

$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from test");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['test_text'];
}
```

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `mysqli_error()`? What does it tell you.

Comment: I added my query code to the op. @PhilipWhitehouse, I have not checked it. I'll do so now.

Comment: `$con` won't be available in the query code's context because of scope. You'll have to `return` it from the connect function

Comment: No error returned from mysqli_error().

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have already tried to return it, to no avail.

Comment: That's the way to go though. (you'll additionally have to assign it to a variable: `$con = databaseConnect();`)

Comment: @Pekka웃 You sir have made my day. It was the mix of both returning the variable out of the function and assigning the function call to the a $con variable locally. Care to explain why both are necessary?

Comment: @ckbrumb if you return something from a function, you need to do something on the "receiving" end - otherwise the value will be returned and vanish into nothing, so to speak. If you call `databaseConnect()` and return `$con` in it, it becomes a value that you can use - but you *have to use it*, for example by assigning it to a variable `$con = databaseConnect();`. The initial variable `$con` exists only inside the `databaseConnect()` function. (hope that makes it clearer)

Answer (score 2):

`$con` is inaccessible as it is defined within the function and not globally, meaning it is not within the scope of accessibility for `mysqli_query`. Try the following:

```
$con = NULL;
function databaseConnect()
{
    global $con;
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use `$con` pretty much where ever you would like.

Comment: Or, you can return the connection. Global variables tend to clutter the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem is easy! You must use "return" inside your function. If you do not use "return", the return data will be null.

```
function databaseConnect()
{
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', "test", "test", "tats");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
return $con;
}
```

Calling function:

```
  $con=databaseConnect();
```